# Unable to execute the create statement generate by cursor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
DECLARE @COLNAME VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @CREATE VARCHAR (1000)
DECLARE @TYPE VARCHAR(1)
SET @COLNAME = ''
SET @TYPE = 5
SET @CREATE = 'CRATE TABLE TABLE_TYPE_' + @TYPE + '('


DECLARE MyCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Name FROM LAYOUT WHERE RecordType = @TYPE
ORDER BY Start

OPEN MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @COLNAME


    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    SET @COLNAME = REPLACE(@COLNAME, 'WX-', '')
    SET @COLNAME = REPLACE(@COLNAME, '(', '')
    SET @COLNAME = REPLACE(@COLNAME, ')', '')
    SET @CREATE = @CREATE + '[' + @COLNAME + ']' + ' VARCHAR(1000),'
    FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @COLNAME
    END


    CLOSE MyCursor
    DEALLOCATE MyCursor
    SET @CREATE = LEFT(@CREATE, len(@CREATE) -1) + ')' --get rid of last comma
    PRINT (@CREATE)   --EXEC (@CREATE)
```

It seem like there is the maximum limit on MS. When I print the @CREATE, many rows have been cut off.
EX. There are 300 columns but somehow it can only print out up to 200 columns
How can I gerenrate the create table statements without any cut offs.

I know some people will suggest don't use the cursor, but since there are so many columns for one table, it will be very time consuming to type out all the columns name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should not use a cursor for that. 
Not only is it possible to do without a cursor, it's simpler:

```
DECLARE @CREATE VARCHAR (max),
        @TYPE int = 5

SET @CREATE = 'CRATE TABLE TABLE_TYPE_' + CAST(@TYPE as varchar) + '('

SELECT @CREATE = @CREATE + REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
              REPLACE([Name], 'WX-', ''),
            '(', ''),
        ')', '') + ' VARCHAR(1000),'
FROM Layout
WHERE RecordType = @TYPE

SET @CREATE = LEFT(@CREATE, len(@CREATE) -1) + ')' --get rid of last comma

PRINT @CREATE
```

[see fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/733da/4)